# Which SQL Transaction Isolation Level to be used?

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions, ado.net, isolation-level

We have developed application with VB.NET as front end and SQL Server as back end. When one transaction is running(Saving) data in  “Table1” then that table is not readable until the running transaction is not committed.

Which transaction lock we should use to avoid dirty read / data garbage?

Comment: Each isolation level prevents different types of anomalies, it depends how careful you want to be as to how high a level you need.

Comment: Thanks charlie. But can u suggest the appropriate lock as per my requirements

Comment: No I cannot suggest an appropriate one: as I said, it entirely depends on things that you haven't mentioned. I can suggest which one *not* to use `READ UNCOMMITED` aka `NOLOCK` which is bad for all kinds of reasons. Most people just use `READ COMMITTED`. But `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` is nice, but you do have to be aware of it when doing updates and deletes. `SERIALIZABLE` is the one to aim for, but it can be very heavy on locking, and cause a lot of deadlocks, if you don't have a lot of concurrent access this is the one to use.

Comment: Thanks. I want to go with READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1):

The default isolation level is `READ COMMITTED` and it is ok to use the default isolation level. If you want a more pessimistic isolation level try with `SERIALIZABLE`.

More about `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-t-sql-transaction-isolation-levels-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

Comment: Hello Emin. Already we are using default lock but other user has to wait untill the existing transaction complete. The wait is more than 5 minutes some time. Because the transaction is an  attendance register. There are 200 employees and the daily attendance are filled by 5 different users. Serialize we can not use as it locks tables. Plz suggest

Comment: @MaheshPatel then take a look at SNAPSHOT isolation level, but for that isolation level you have to do some database changes because it requires TempDB.

Comment: Thanks. I want to go with READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

To prevent only **dirty read**, set `READ COMMITTED` which is default isolation level on **SQL Server**:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

And, if you want to prevent more problems, set other isolation level as shown below. ***`Yes`** means ***Occurs***, **`No`** means ***Doesn't occur***. You can see more details about [**transaction isolation levels on SQL Server**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-ver16):

| Isolation Level | Dirty Read | Non-Repeatable Read | Phantom Read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **READ UNCOMMITTED** | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| **READ COMMITTED** | **No** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| **READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT** | **No** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| **REPEATABLE READ** | **No** | **No** | **Yes** |
| **SNAPSHOT** | **No** | **No** | **No** |
| **SERIALIZABLE** | **No** | **No** | **No** |